# angular model render problem

Tags: angularjs

```
<form class="no-print" ng-if="can('add_conclusion')" name="editConclusion" ng-submit="save(conclusion)">
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label translate>Discription</label>
            <textarea ng-model="conclusion.description" columns="1" rows="5" ng-required="true"></textarea>

        <p>{{conclusion.description}}</p>
    </form>
```

в этом положении работает норм, но если вынести:

```
<p>{{conclusion.description}}</p>
```

ниже - вот так:

```
<form class="no-print" ng-if="can('add_conclusion')" name="editConclusion" ng-submit="save(conclusion)">
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label translate>Discription</label>
            <textarea ng-model="conclusion.description" columns="1" rows="5" ng-required="true"></textarea>
    </form>
    <md-content layout-padding>      
            <p>{{conclusion.description}}</p>
    </md-content>
```

то в таком контексте в `conclusion.description` уже не рендерятся переменные с модели. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: нужно больше кода, что за `conclusion`, что за `md-content`? вы уверены что внутри него можно размещать разметку и она будет показываться?

Comment: И почему у вас не закрыт <md-input-container> ?